# What masked character is on this t-shirt?

Tags: character-identification

I've got a riddle for you. I am pretty sure that I know this character, but I forgot the name. Could you help me to identify it?

[image: Someone wearing a t-shirt with a masked character on it]

Comment: It might help if we had context for the picture: who's wearing it, what the event is, etc.

Comment: A girl, it was probably completely random choice of shirt in her case cause of the fact that I was in Cracow on some kind of performance. The shirt just intrigued me, it seems familiar for me.

Comment: How do we know that the character depicted on the shirt is from fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: @user14111 - See below. He isn't.

Comment: That’s not [a riddle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riddle).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - "*Riddle: Def #2 - Something that is confusing, or a problem that is difficult to solve*"; http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riddle

Comment: @Valorum: is recognising a mask confusing or difficult?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'd say that it was moderately difficult. If you didn't recognise the style of mask, you'd probably find it near-impossible

Comment: @Valorum: well it’s like a quiz isn’t it. If you recognise it, it’s easy. If you don’t, it’s impossible. You either know it, or you don’t.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well no. I recognised that it was a luchador mask (having seen them before in an episode of Angel). I then needed to search through a page of famous wrestlers to find the right one. It wasn't *trivially simple* to answer.

Comment: @Valorum: sure, it took effort. It just doesn’t sound like the sort of intellectual flavour of challenge I think of as a necessary component of a riddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is actually a luchador (Mexican wrestler) named [Rey Misterio Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rey_Mysterio) rather than a superhero. His trademark mask, cut off above the mouth, has a very recognisable catholic-style cross on it, along with blackened eyes and black "flames" above the eyes.

[image]

Comment: In fact 'superhero' :D
Well i guess that is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I'm tickled that Sr. Misterio apparently has fans as far-flung as Krakow.

Comment: no, that's Jr. Mysterio. Sr. Misterio is his uncle, he's much older.